# Accents in Paypal IPN returns INVALID

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've got a problem: 
I'm creating a Paypal IPN server in PHP. And I'm triggering it with the IPN simulator, works good. The problem is when in some field I introduce an accent (I'm from an hispanic county), it returns INVALID! I've tried to encode the $value var (you might see the code for understand it) with urlencode and htmlentities (not together) but it doesn't work. Do you know what can I do?
At least say if it's somethink I need to worry about.

```
<?php
//$url='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

$postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $postFields .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
));

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fh=fopen('result.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $result.' -- '.$postFields);
fclose($fh);

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `urlencode` on the `$value` var in your `$postfields` ?

Comment: @Derek Pollard Yes. I've said it. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what works (just on live, not sandbox):

> If the customer name, or address has accented characters and they do not appear correctly on your site after the user has purchased something then chances are the IPN from paypal was not in UTF-8 format.
>   To set this log into your paypal account.
>   Then after logging in go to this page:
>   https://www.paypal.com/ie/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-language-encoding
>
> After going to that page click on "more option" just below the input 
>   box.
>  Then for your websites encoding option (encoding selection box)
>   select  "utf-8" from the drop down.
>  Then in the next setting leave it
>   set to "yes" and hit "save". That should correct the issue.

Source: http://www.ktools.net/photostore/documentation.php?fid=276